# При проигрывании событий с WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK ничего не меняется

Tags: winapi, hook, windows-7

Кто-нибудь использовал хук WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK в Windows 7? Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой...

При проигрывании событий с помощью хука `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` на экране ничего не меняется. Функция получает `HC_GETNEXT` и `HC_SKIP` поочередно, из чего следует, что приложение проглатывает сообщения. Пробовал проигрывать без задержки (с возвращаемым значением 0) и с другими значениями. С задержкой (которая работает, не так, как описано в документации) `HC_GETNEXT` проскакивает дважды перед каждым `HC_SKIP`. Пробовал искусственно вставлять `WM_PAINT` между сообщениями. Никакого эффекта. Заметил, что при закрытии окна с помощью мыши, при проигрывании все-таки всплывает подсказка "Закрыть" около кнопки (это вся реакция).